# What's wrong with the http response message in the pictures?

Tags: http, response, httpresponse, response-headers

my teacher tell me that there is `one error` in the `response message`, But I think there is no error.

Please help me out,
thanks.

Here is the response message:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n
Server: nginx \r\n
Content-Type: test/html\r\n
Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2018 08:08:24 GMT\r\n
Location: https://www.bbc.co.uk/\r\n
Content-Length: 17\r\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
\r\n
<html><head><title>301Moved Permanently</title></head>\r\n
<body bgcolor="white"><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></body></html>\r\n
```

[The picture of the response message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j60zX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Content-Length: 17\r\n
```

The content is longer than 17 bytes:

```
<html><head><title>301Moved Permanently</title></head>\r\n
<body bgcolor="white"><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></body></html>\r\n
```

Comment: @ying-po So did this answer your question and/or solve your problem? (the wrong content length is that `one error`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are right.
I cannot cast a vote now, I will do it if I can.

Comment: @YingPo Maybe you can accept the answer? :)